# Docker no such host error - Gitlab runner How to provide the correct service name image?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

When running a job on gitlab.com I got this error:

```
error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

This was my job pipeline:

```
apply-terraform:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  environment: ${GCP_PROJECT}
  before_script:
    - base64 -d $GCP_SA_KEY_B64 | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5
  script:
    - <...>
```

Checking [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-no-such-host-error), it says that when the service's image url includes a registry hostname, like in my case that is a private google container registry, this error happens.

> A service’s hostname is derived from the full image name. However, the shorter service hostname docker is expected. To allow service resolution and access, add an explicit alias for the service name docker: ...

So I did:

```
apply-terraform:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind
      alias: docker
  needs:
    - "deploy-ewx-search"
  environment: ${GCP_PROJECT}
  before_script:
    - base64 -d $GCP_SA_KEY_B64 | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5
  script:
```

But after running again, now the service name to login to my google container registry is not the correct now.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.9.0~beta.115.g598a7c91 (598a7c91)
  on blue-1.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default j1aLDqxS, system ID: s_b437a71a38f9
  feature flags: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD:true, FF_USE_IMPROVED_URL_MASKING:true
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:30
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: invalid service name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: invalid service name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
ERROR: Preparation failed: invalid service name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): invalid service name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind
```

I am checking [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1074274/499906) and it says that a map to the docker socket should be added alongside adding `privileged=true"` to fix the first `Docker no such host error` issue, but that is for the case if I am using a gitlab local runner, not the cloud.

Do I need to do this? If so how can I do it for the `etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` runner config?

I also see something similar here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-the-docker-executor-with-docker-in-docker but not sure how to proceed in an eventual case.

Comment: `Do I need to do this?` What does "this" refer to exactly? To execute docker login, you have to have _some_ docker deamon running. To which docker _deamon_ you want to connect to? `how can I do it for the etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml runner config?` You can mount the _host_ docker daemon to inside your container, or you can export DOCKER_HOST environment variable to connect to some external docker deamon on a different host if you want to.

Comment: I see, then such as my pipeline is right now, it does not have docker daemon included, I am trying if adding it as a service such as is stated [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#use-docker-in-docker-with-privileged-mode) can be helpful

Comment: Yes, but `invalid service name: https://eu.gcr.io/my-gcp-project/deployer-terraform:1.3.5-dind`. Remove `https://`.